# How to get lot size script to work with NinjaTrader

Tags: c#, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm not a very advanced programmer, just learning.

I have successfully managed to get a script to increase the trading size from 1 contract to 2 contracts if the last trade was a loser.

I did this by declaring the following variables

```
private int OrderQuantity = 1;
    private int OrderQuantityMultiplier1 = 2;`
```

And then I wrote the following rule

```
int orderQuantity = OrderQuantity;
            
            if( SystemPerformance.AllTrades.Count > 0 )
        
                if( SystemPerformance.AllTrades[SystemPerformance.AllTrades.Count-1].ProfitTicks < 0 ) // last trade is a loss
                    orderQuantity = Math.Max(1, Convert.ToInt32(orderQuantity * OrderQuantityMultiplier1));
                       EnterLongLimit(orderQuantity, (Low[0] + (1 * TickSize)) ,"");;}
```

And that works fine. But then I wanted to say, if the last trade was a loser go from 1 lot to 2 lots. If the last 2 trades were a loser increase from a 2 to a 4 lot and so on.

I created these variables

```
private int OrderQuantityMultiplier2 = 4;
    private int OrderQuantityMultiplier3 = 8;
    private int OrderQuantityMultiplier4 = 16;`
```

and wrote this code

```
int orderQuantity = OrderQuantity;
            
            if( SystemPerformance.AllTrades.Count > 0 )
        
                if( SystemPerformance.AllTrades[SystemPerformance.AllTrades.Count-1].ProfitTicks < 0 ) // last trade is a loss
                    orderQuantity = Math.Max(1, Convert.ToInt32(orderQuantity * OrderQuantityMultiplier1));
                       EnterLongLimit(orderQuantity, (Low[0] + (1 * TickSize)) ,"");;}
        
        if( SystemPerformance.AllTrades[SystemPerformance.AllTrades.Count-2].ProfitTicks < 0 ) // last trade is a loss
                    orderQuantity = Math.Max(1, Convert.ToInt32(orderQuantity * OrderQuantityMultiplier2));
                       EnterLongLimit(orderQuantity, (Low[0] + (1 * TickSize)) ,"");;}
```

But I'm getting the following errors

[image: Errors]

> NinjaScript File  Error   Code    Line    Column
> Intraday1.cs    The name 'orderQuantity' does not exist in the current context  CS0103  105 7

I assume there's probably a quicker way of doing this than writing out If last 2 trades losers, if last 3 trades losers over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are asking about how to get rid of the error or something else, so I am going to assume that that is what you need.

The error you are getting looks like a problem of variables scope, although its difficult to tell because you didn't tell us where in your strategy you included the code you are showing. Still, most likely your problem will be solved by declaring your variables in the way I am showing in the following example.

I included the skeleton for a NinjaTrader Strategy. I hope it helps you:

```
#region Using declarations
.
.
.
#endregion

//This namespace holds Strategies in this folder and is required. Do not change it. 
namespace NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Strategies
{
    public class myStrategy : Strategy
    {
        // STEP 1: Declare here any variables you want to make available for the entire strategy.
        // So, put your variables here like this:
        private int OrderQuantity = 1;
        private int OrderQuantityMultiplier1 = 2;
        private int OrderQuantityMultiplier2 = 4;
        private int OrderQuantityMultiplier4 = 16;
        private int OrderQuantityMultiplier3 = 8;
        // This is the place to declare objects like indicators and Series for example:
        private SMA SMA1;
        private EMA EMA1;
        private Series<double> mInnerMA;

        protected override void OnStateChange()
        {
            if (State == State.SetDefaults)
            {
                .
                .
                .
            }
            else if (State == State.Configure)
            {
            }
            else if (State == State.DataLoaded)
            {               
                // Instatiate Series here:
                mInnerMA = new Series<double>(this);
                SMA1 = SMA(Close, Convert.ToInt32(SMA_Period));
                EMA1 = EMA(Close, Convert.ToInt32(EMA_Period));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnBarUpdate()
        {
            // Makes sure we have data for the indicators
            if (BarsInProgress != 0) 
                return;

            if (CurrentBars[0] < 20)
                return;


            // Here you develop your strategy and all variables are going to be available
            .
            .
            .   // STEP 2: Make use of any variables defined on STEP 1

        }
        
        // This is the place for functions
        private void Function1(int parameter1, double parameter2, ...)
        {
            // This is the place to declare variables that are local for this particular function
            // These variables are not visible for the rest of the code, not even for other functions, 
            // only for this particula function
            int var1;
            string var2;
            .
            .   // STEP 3: Even here you can use the variables defined on STEP 1
            .   // although not a pretty habit, but it will not produce errors
            .
            return (var1);      // This is the only value that will go out from Function1
        }

        #region Properties
        // NinjaTrader generated code
        .
        .
        .
        #endregion
    }
}
```